# SwiftUI- Missing argument for parameter 'at' in call

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm following a [CoreData tutorial](https://youtu.be/gGM_Qn3CUfQ?t=2262) and want to delete items from a list. For iPhone in this case would be `.onDelete(perform: deleteBudget)` to swipe and delete.

But I'm developing for macOS instead, using `.contextMenu`  to right click and delete.

I'm getting this error next to deleteBudget() in the button inside the contextMenu:

> Missing argument for parameter 'at' in call

I'm not sure the correct parameters to include with 'at'.

Content View

```
@ObservedObject private var budgetListVML: BudgetListViewModel

     init(vm: BudgetListViewModel){
                self.budgetListVML = vm
            }
        
   

 private func deleteBudget(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        offsets.forEach { index in
                let budget = budgetListVML.budgets[index]
                budgetListVML.deleteBudget(budgetId: budget.id)
            }
        

  List{
        ForEach(budgetListVML.budgets) { budget in
               NavigationLink{....
                }
               .contextMenu { 
                        Button {
                            deleteBudget()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Delete Budget")
                        }
                }
        }
            
  }
```

BudgetListViewModel

```
class BudgetListViewModel:NSObject, ObserverableObject {
@Published var budgets = [BudgetViewModel]()
.......
    func deleteBudget(budgetId: NSManagedObjectID){
        do {
            guard let budget = try context.existingObject(with: budgetId) as? Budget else {
                return
        }
        try budget.delete()
        
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
....
}

 struct BudgetViewModel: Identifiable {
    private var budget: Budget
    
    init(budget: Budget) {
        self.budget = budget
    }


    var id: NSManagedObjectID {
        budget.objectID
          }

    var name: String {
        budget.name ?? ""
          }
       }
```

Comment: You are suppose to use @ FetchRequest as the view model. And use the context in @ Environment to delete the managed object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `deleteBudget` function has an `at` parameter in its definition:

```
private func deleteBudget(at offsets: IndexSet) {
                          ^^ <--- Here
```

This is useful when using, for example `List`'s `onDelete` which passes an `IndexSet`.

For your use case, where you don't have an `IndexSet` within the `contextMenu`, I'd suggest making a `deleteBudget` function that takes a `Budget` directly:

```
private func deleteBudget(_ budget : Budget) {
   budgetListVML.deleteBudget(budget)
}
```

and in your `contextMenu`, call:

```
.contextMenu { 
   Button {
     deleteBudget(budget)
   } label: {
     Text("Delete Budget")
   }
}
```

and in your view model:

```
func deleteBudget(_ budget: Budget){
    do {
      try budget.delete()
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, getting this error 'Cannot convert value of type 'ObjectIdentifier' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObjectID' highlighted on budget.id

Comment: Try the edit -- easier just to pass the `Budget` around without doing the casting

Comment: Getting this error highlighted inside the button on deleteBudget(budget) 'Cannot convert value of type 'BudgetViewModel' to expected argument type 'Budget''.

Comment: Okay, so use `deleteBudget(budget.budget)`. (I'm not sure why you're wrapping `Budget` inside `BudgetViewModel` anyway, but that's a separate issue.